# Grep for leading white-spaces in-front of required text

Tags: grep, whitespace

I need to `grep` for the file name that exists between a white-space and the file extension. Example:

```
[meghanak@cycrh6rtp32 CIT]$ echo -e "Akqmskdnlcn shddhjshd.py" | grep "[[:space:]]*.py"
-e Akqmskdnlcn shddhjshd.py
```

But I want result as:

```
shddhjshd.py
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ echo -e "Akqmskdnlcn shddhjshd.py" | grep -o "[^[:space:]]*\.py"
shddhjshd.py
```

`^` is to negate the catching group. Work with `[:space:]` means characters not space.
`-o` is only to only print out matched contents.

Comment: Can i use it in this expression?? '(?<=[[:space:]])(\n|.)*?(?=\.py)'

Comment: @Megumi  You can try it. But I cannot understand why you put `\n` inside it. Also you want `.py` part or not? If you want it then don't put them in `(?=)`.  Also the right way to match `.py` is `\.py` -- `.` has special meaning so needs to `escape` it.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use another tool after grep, `cut` makes this very easy:

```
$ echo -e "Akqmskdnlcn shddhjshd.py" | grep "[[:space:]]*.py" \
    | cut -d' ' -f2
shddhjshd.py
```

If you need to only use `grep`, you turn things around and match any "non-space" non-space (\S) which precedes ".py", and then use the -o flag to pring the match, and there you have it:

```
$ echo -e "Akqmskdnlcn shddhjshd.py" | grep -o "\S*.py"
shddhjshd.py
```

Answer (score 0):

With Awk

```
$echo "Akqmskdnlcn shddhjshd.py" | awk -F' ' '{print $2}'
shddhjshd.py
```

or

```
echo "Akqmskdnlcn shddhjshd" | awk -F' ' ' $2 ~ /.*.py/{print $2}'
```